# Prerequisite on types?

Tags: haskell

I have a type `Foo a` and want a type `EnumFoo a` that requires `instance Enum (Foo a)`. How do you declare this type?

Let's say we declare `Foo` like this:

```
type Foo a = Maybe a
```

There can be `Foo Int`, `Foo String` and anything.
Now I declare an instance of `Enum` on `Foo Int`:

```
instance Enum (Foo Int) where
  ...
```

There might be some other `Foo` that has an instance of `Enum` like this. Let's call those types `EnumFoo a`. How do you express it?

This is not working but what I would like to do:

```
type (Enum (Foo a)) => EnumFoo a = Foo a
```

I am not sure what it's called, so the title should be making no sense.

Comment: It almost makes sense, but not quite. Can you try to explain a little more what you're after? If you can give a bit of context, that will help a lot.

Comment: @dfeuer I just added some more. Does it make sense?

Comment: I see two interpretations: (a) `EnumFoo` is trying to capture the collection of types which are `Foo a` such that there is an instance `Enum (Foo a)`. Or (b) `EnumFoo a` is a "type function" that resolves to `Foo a` whenever there is an instance `Enum (Foo a)`.  Are either of these close?  Something else?

Comment: There's the now-deprecated `DatatypeContexts` extension that would let you do it for `data (Enum (Foo a)) => EnumFoo a = EnumFoo (Foo a)` along with `-XFlexibleContexts`, but you'd probably be better off with `-XGADTs` and `data EnumFoo a where EnumFoo :: (Enum (Foo a)) => Foo a -> EnumFoo a`.  Would write up a full answer but I'm headed to bed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As bheklilr [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28492830/prerequisite-on-types?noredirect=1#comment45306517_28492830), it sounds like what you want is a GADT:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
module Foo where

data Foo a = Foo (Maybe a)

data EnumFoo a where
  EnumFoo :: Enum (Foo a) => Foo a -> EnumFoo a
```

The only way to make an `EnumFoo a` (aside from `undefined`) is to apply the `EnumFoo` constructor, which imposes an `Enum (Foo a)` context. You can then write things like

```
blah :: EnumFoo a -> [EnumFoo a]
blah (EnumFoo foo) = map EnumFoo [toEnum 1 .. foo]
```

Note that you need the `FlexibleContexts` extension because standard Haskell doesn't allow a context like `Enum (Foo a)`; it only allows simple things like `Enum Foo` or `Enum a`.

bheklilr also mentioned an older declaration form, putting a context on a standard `data` declaration. While this form is standard Haskell (it is in the Haskell 98 and Haskell 2010 Reports), it is so widely considered a misfeature that GHC does not even allow it without a `LANGUAGE` pragma. The problem is that while it constrains what the type variables are allowed to be, it doesn't let you make use of these constraints.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but is there any methods to translate an instance to an object? Or should I post another question

Comment: @RyoichiroOka, I don't understand what you mean.